# mySql to get last records of duplicate entries

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Hi all i am having my table data as follows

```
ID   FedTaxID  RegularPay  Payperiodnumber

1    562545366   500            1
2    562545366   501            1
3    562545366   5000           2
```

I would like to get my data as follows

```
 ID    FedTaxID    RegularPay   Payperiodnumber
 2     562545366     501            1
 3     562545366     5000           2
```

I tried some thing like as follow but i am not getting the required result

```
select max(id) ID,regularpay,fedtaxid,payperiodnumber
from tblemployeegrosswagesn1 where fedtaxid="562545366"
group by payperiodnumber
having count(*) >= 1;
```

Can any one help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should give you the desired result:

```
SELECT      t.ID, 
            t.FedTaxID, 
            t.RegularPay, 
            t.Payperiodnumber

FROM        tblemployeegrosswagesn1 t
INNER JOIN  (SELECT MAX(ID) AS MaxId, 
                    FedTaxID, 
                    Payperiodnumber 
             FROM  tblemployeegrosswagesn1  
             GROUP BY FedTaxID, Payperiodnumber) AS InnerQuery ON t.ID = InnerQuery.MaxId AND t.Payperiodnumber = InnerQuery.Payperiodnumber AND t.FedTaxID = InnerQuery.FedTaxID

WHERE        t.FedTaxID = '562545366';
```

I am intrigued by the link newtover posted; In this instance, though, you want the max id per payperiodnumber so you'll have to adapt that a bit more. It will look something like:

```
SELECT              t.Id,
                    t.FedTaxId,
                    t.RegularPay,
                    t.Payperiodnumber

FROM                tblemployeegrosswagesn1 t

LEFT JOIN           tblemployeegrosswagesn1 t1  ON (t.FedTaxId = t1.FedTaxId AND t.Payperiodnumber = t1.PayperiodNumber AND t.id < t1.id)   

WHERE               t1.ID IS NULL   
AND                 t.FedTaxId = '562545366'
```

Which is much simpler to read. Many thanks to @BillKarwin for a neat set based solution. Thanks for the chance to learn a new (and better given the link posted) way of doing something.

Comment: This one also works but the simpler is [Check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Comment: Marked as answer as it resolved